# What does ~fs.readdirSync mean in config files?

Tags: javascript

In many javascript source code(mostly, config file), with code like

```
process.env.NODE_ENV = ~fs.readdirSync(configPath).map(function(file) {
    console.log(file);
    console.log(file.slice(0, -3));
    //The file is something like all.js. After use file.slice(0, -3) the output is like alljavascri
    return file.slice(0, -3);
}).indexOf(process.env.NODE_ENV) ? process.env.NODE_ENV : 'development';
```

My questions is, what does `~fs.readdirSync` means? The `~` here doesn't look like xor.

Comment: It's bitwise NOT, not XOR.

Comment: do you have a specific example of a module where this is used? i'm not sure exactly why somebody would do this since ~[] === -1, but maybe seeing the inner map function would help.

Comment: There's very likely more to the overall statement. Can you provide an example?

Comment: Sure, sample code updated.

Comment: oh, ok your edit makes it more clear, the indexOf and ternary operation there completely change what this does.

Comment: See Pointy's answer in the duplicate question.

Answer (score 1):

`~` is the [bitwise NOT](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators#Bitwise_NOT) operator NOT. Every bit in `x` is inverted in `~x`. For instance:

```
 x = 00011011
~x = 11100100
```

Alternatively, it is equivalent to doing XOR with `0xFFFFFFFF` (all 1-bits):

```
     00011011
 XOR 11111111
     --------
   = 11100100
```

Comment: I checked javascript logical operators but didn't find it https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators.  And, what's the meaning of the entire line of code? thank you

Comment: It's not a logical operator, it's a bitwise operator. The difference is that logical operators work on the whole operand and returns either true or false, while bitwise operators work on each bit of the operands and return an integer.